# Use Linq to get details from a database so people can't create a new entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Just learning C# and I'm developing a program from home.

I have an appointments entity in my application. I want to have it so someone can put their details down with a choice of rooms, dates and administrators (FK) at their disposal.

When they hit the button to create, I want the Linq Query to perform a search to see if all the criteria is available, i.e. that the appointment can be made.
I'm just struggling with it at the moment.

Here is what I have:

```
 var currentBooking = db.Appointments
        .Where(b => b.AppointmentId == appointments.AppointmentId)
        .Select(b => (appointments.RoomType == b.RoomType && appointments.DateOfAppointment == b.DateOfAppointment && appointments.AdministrationId == b.AdministrationId))
        .FirstOrDefault();

            if (currentBooking)
            {
                throw new Exception("The Room is already out on that date.");
            }
            else
            {
                db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Comment: If based on what you said this is a new appointment then it should not have an id set as yet. Next you can simple query using `Any` to verify that the filter exists.

Comment: We use [remote validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) for these kind of checks (uniqueness, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If based on what you said this is a new appointment then it should not have an id set as yet. Next you can simple query using `Any` to verify that the filter exists.

```
var currentBooking = db.Appointments
    .Any(b => appointments.RoomType == b.RoomType 
        && appointments.DateOfAppointment == b.DateOfAppointment 
        && appointments.AdministrationId == b.AdministrationId);

if (currentBooking) {
    throw new Exception("The Room is already out on that date.");
} else {
    db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```